# Create 12 months rollover data inside a java object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a java object like this `Map<Integer, Long> monthCaseCountMap`

This object contains data in the format like below :

```
202103, 2
202104, 4
202105, 0
202106, 9
.
.
.
.
202202, 10
```

First value is a month key, second value is case count.

I need to create a monthly rollover data or accumulation of case count month by month.

The result should look like -

```
202103, 2
202104, 6
202105, 6
202106, 15
.
.
.
.
202202, 98
```

How can we do this in using Java streams or using any other method.

Thank you @eritren for providing the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option could be to use AtomicLong to store the sum and collect the accumulated values in to a new map:

```
Map<Integer, Long> monthCaseCountMap = Map.of(  202103, 2L,
                                                202104, 4L,
                                                202105, 0L,
                                                202106, 9L);

AtomicLong sum = new AtomicLong(0L);

Map<Integer, Long> accumulated = 
        monthCaseCountMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> sum.addAndGet(e.getValue())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong tool for the job. Java streams are the right tool for the job when the operations you need to do are either [A] an operation solely on a single element of a stream, or [B] an operation on all of them.

You want an operation on some of them (specifically, the 'predecessors'). Stream, fundamentally, wasn't designed for that. You're using the wrong tool for the job. Stream has `.parallel()` for example, and in that view, the concept of 'the sum of all stuff before me' doesn't even make sense anymore.

You can redefine the problem by involving the notion of sorting ("I want the sum of all values from this key and everything that sorts before this key") but this would be ridiculously inefficient.

As is expectable when you attempt to use a tool for something it wasn't designed for, the stream version of this is either much slower, or an abomination (mixing stream and non-stream concepts, hence getting the downsides of both and the upsides of neither), and most likely much more code and much more complicated code.

Just use iterative processes - the operation as you've defined is is much simpler with an iterative mindset. If you want to improve your code, remember: You should use the most specific type that accurately describes what you have. `Integer` doesn't say much, `LocalDate` is much more accurate, as the keys in your map are clearly dates, or at least, months+years.

```java
public class Hospital {
  SortedMap<LocalDate, Long> caseCounts = createCaseCountMap();
// createCaseCountMap ends up doing something like:
//    caseCounts.put(LocalDate.of(2021, 03, 1), 2);
//    caseCounts.put(LocalDate.of(2021, 04, 1), 4);
//    .... etc

// option 1:

  public long getSumUntil(LocalDate mark) {
    return caseCounts.headMap(mark, true).values().stream()
      .mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum();
  }

// option 2:

  public SortedMap<LocalDate, Long> makeIncrementalMap() {
    var out = new TreeMap<LocalDate, Long>();
    long sum = 0L;
    for (var entry : caseCounts.entrySet()) {
      sum += entry.getValue();
      out.put(entry.getKey(), sum);
    }
    return out;
  }
}
```

Here, for option 2, using streams is a very silly idea, given that the operation fundamentally depends on some but not all of its neighbours, which streams weren't meant for.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to *sort* the entries that you might make you of the `TreeMap`.

And then want to solve this problem with streams at all costs to accumulate the *values* you might mimic the iteration over the *entry set* with for loop using the `iterate()` method.

The *first entry* of the sorted map is used as a **seed**. Then for every consecutive entry created in the stream, a key of the higher entry will be used as a key of a new entry and as value a sum of the value of the higher entry and a value of the previous entry from the stream. The process will continue until the higher entry exists, i.e. result returned by the `getAccumulatedEntry()` is not `null`. This condition is represented by the predicate `Objects::nonNull`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Long> monthCaseCount =
            Map.of(202103, 2L,
                    202104, 4L,
                    202105, 0L,
                    202106, 9L);

    NavigableMap<Integer, Long> monthCaseCountSorted = new TreeMap<>(monthCaseCount);

    Map<Integer, Long> monthCaseCountAccumulated =
            Stream.iterate(monthCaseCountSorted.firstEntry(),
                           Objects::nonNull,
                           entry -> getAccumulatedEntry(monthCaseCountSorted, entry))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

    monthCaseCountAccumulated.entrySet().stream() // this part was added only for demonstration purpose
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("%d : %d%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}

private static Map.Entry<Integer, Long> getAccumulatedEntry(NavigableMap<Integer, Long> monthCaseCountSorted,
                                                            Map.Entry<Integer, Long> entry) {
    Integer higher = monthCaseCountSorted.higherKey(entry.getKey());

    return higher == null ?
            null : Map.entry(higher, entry.getValue() + monthCaseCountSorted.get(higher));
}
```

**output**

```
202103 : 2
202104 : 6
202105 : 6
202106 : 15
```

***Note:** the more efficient approach is to adjust the values in the `monthCaseCountSorted` map. And streams are not appropriate for such a task. Functions must not cause side effects and every execution of the function must have the same outcome (if you'll try to implement a stream-based solution by changing values in the `monthCaseCountSorted` directly both these conditions will be violated)*